# Is there a data race in this code?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, valgrind

In [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_one), this sample code is written to explain how to use `notify_one`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex cv_m;
int i = 0;
bool done = false;

void waits()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
    std::cout << "Waiting... \n";
    cv.wait(lk, []{return i == 1;});
    std::cout << "...finished waiting. i == 1\n";
    done = true;
}

void signals()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::cout << "Notifying...\n";
    cv.notify_one();

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
    i = 1;
    while (!done) {
        lk.unlock();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        lk.lock();
        std::cerr << "Notifying again...\n";
        cv.notify_one();
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(waits), t2(signals);
    t1.join(); t2.join();
}
```

However, valgrind (helgrind, actually) complains that:

> Probably a race condition: condition variable 0x605420 has been
>   signaled but the associated mutex 0x605460 is not locked by the
>   signalling thread.

If the second threads runs before the first one and reaches `cv.notify_one();` before anyone else, it will signals other threads without any lock being hold.

I am actually learning how to use these `condition variables` and trying to understand who should lock/unlock the mutex associated with them. So my question is: is this code doing things right? or is helgrind wrong?

Comment: Without understanding the exact semantics of these concurrency primitives, does it make sense to `unlock` first, and then `lock`?  Unless the mutex is created in a locked state (weird?) then this is gonna behave oddly for the first iteration of your while loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Truth in advertising: I was, until very recently, the architect of a commercial data-race and memory error detector that "competes" with Helgrind/Valgrind.]

There is no data race in your code.  Helgrind is issuing this warning because of a subtlety about the way condition variables work.  There is some discussion about it in [the "hints" section of the Helgrind manual](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html#hg-manual.effective-use).  Briefly: Helgrind is doing happens-before data race detection.  It derives the "happens-before" relation by observing the order in which your code is calling pthread_mutex_lock/unlock and pthread_cond_wait/signal (these are the C primitives upon which the C++11 primitives are implemented.)

If you follow the discipline that your `cv.notify_one()` calls are always protected by the same mutex that surrounds the corresponding `cv.wait()` calls then Helgrind knows that the *mutexes* will enforce the correct happens-before relationship and so everything will be okay.

In your case Helgrind is complaining about the initial (gratuitous) `cv.notify_one()` call at the top of `signals()`, *before* you acquire the lock on `cv_m`.  It knows that this is the kind of situation that can confuse it (although the real confusion is that it might later report false positives, so the warning message here is a bit misleading.)

**Please note** the advice to "use semaphores instead of condition_variables" in the hints section of the Helgrind manual is *horrible* advice.  Semaphores are much harder to check for correctness than condition variables both for tools *and for humans*.  Semaphores are "too general" in the sense that there are all sorts of invariants you can not rely on.  The same thread that "locks" with a semaphore doesn't have to be the thread that "unlocks".  Two threads that "wait" on a non-binary semaphore may or may not have a happens-before relationship.  So semaphores are pretty much useless if you are trying to reason (or automatically detect) deadlock or data race conditions.

Better advice is to use condition variables to signal/wait, but to make sure that you follow a discipline where all calls on a particular condition variable happen within critical sections protected by the same mutex.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, there is no problem.

In general, issues can arise if there is a third thread that may be using the same mutex, or if it's possible that the waiting thread may destroy the condition variable when it finishes running.

It's just safer to lock the mutex while signalling, to ensure that the signalling code entirely runs before the woken up code.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:  Turns out this isn't true, but it's being preserved here because @dauphic's explanation of why it isn't true in the comments is helpful.**

You have reversed the order of `unlock` and `lock` in your `while` loop, such that you are attempting to unlock the mutex before you have ever locked it, which would seem consistent with the valgrind message you are seeing.

Comment: I'm not seeing this; the mutex is locked before the while loop is entered.

Comment: Is it?  I cannot claim any knowledge of the C++11 concurrency primitives in use. Where is the mutex locked prior to entering the while loop?

Comment: C++11 has a series of `lock` classes, in this case `unique_lock`, that locks a mutex in the constructor and unlocks it in the destructor.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation.  I'll mark edit my answer to reflect the fact that it's not true, but leave it here because your explanation is possibly helpful to future visitors.